# Place an extra lowest_cost_node = None to do variable declaration

Tags: python

I am learning Dijkstran algorithms and read the following code:

```
#dijkstra algorithms

def find_lowest_cost_node(costs):
    #cost is a dict
    lowest_cost = float("inf")
    lowest_cost_node = None

    for node in costs:
        cost = costs[node]
        if cost < lowest_cost and cost not in processed:
            lowest_cost = cost
            lowest_cost_node = node
    return lowest_cost_node
```

I am very curious about the `lowest_cost_node` declaration `lowest_cost_node = None`.
The function works properly if I comment it out,
Why do extra effort to place `lowest_cost_node = None` in the header part?

Comment: What's peps it follows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It takes care of the special case of an empty `costs` dict.

The current code gracefully returns `None`, whereas the modification you're suggesting would fail at run time with an `UnboundLocalError` exception.

P.S. There are several errors in your code but I'm not addressing them since your question isn't about them.